# Loop completes a cycle before getting input, how to fix?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, while-loop

```
while (1)
{
    cout << "Enter the Citizen ID number of the worker or Enter 0 to exit:" << endl;
    getline (cin, j);
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if (workers[i]->IDno == j) 
        {
            wFind = 1;
            cout << "Choose your option:" << endl;
            cout << "1- Display all details of the worker" << endl;
            cout << "2- Display number of the days worker delayed" << endl;
            cout << "3- Display number of the days worker missed" << endl;
            cin >> k;
            switch (k)
            {
            case 1:
                workers[i]->AWorker();
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << workers[i]->TotalDaysDelayed() << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << workers[i]->TotalDaysMissed() << endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            wFind = 0;
    }

    if (wFind == 0)
        cout << "ERROR: No worker has the ID number that you typed!" << endl;
}
```

Note: `wFind` is initialized as `2`.

When I execute this code, I always get this output:

> Enter the Citizen ID number of the worker or Enter 0 to exit:
>   ERROR: No worker has the ID number that you typed!
>   Enter the Citizen ID number of the worker or Enter 0 to exit:

Interestingly enough, my code can complete a cycle in the loop before getting my input for the string `j`. How can this be possible and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You probably want to clear your input buffer between using getline and cin.  Sometimes you get a bit of whitespace in there and it'll break further input, especially into integers.  It's not pretty but the following worked for me: `while (cin.peek() < ' ') { cin.ignore(1); }`

Comment: Don't mix token extraction (`>>`) and line reading (`getline`).

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> k;` will not eat the newline. You need to call `std::getline` after it to consume the newline.

If you're having the problem on the first iteration of the loop, I would presume you have code above this which does not eat the newline as well.

Comment: Calling `cin.ignore` afterwards would be more efficient and more succinct than using `std::getline`.